# MongoDB (C#) BsonSerializer not Deserializing properly

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization, deserialization

Item comparison before and after serialization (JSON): http://pastebin.com/zCWvAQ9G

Disclaimer: Alot of Json was excluded for readability.

The issue lays underneath the works of the MongoDB BsonSerializer.
When the item gets deserialized it sets the "id" to 0, instead of remaining at 2 or the original value. Also the id field then gets placed inside of the extraElement field, this happens when Mongo cant correctly map the json value to a corresponding class field. The class mapping is AutoMapping, I have not made an explicit changes.

Side note: I cannot Use Newtonsoft's JsonConvert due to it not being able to convert the Mongo ObjectId

```
    public static RootObject DeserializeUpdateItem(DataPuller dp,string index, RootObject itemtoupdate)
     {
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        string jsonGraphData = dp.UrlToJson(@"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/" + index + ".json");
        if (jsonGraphData == "Null")
        {
            return null;
        }
        string finalJsonItem = JsonMerger.MergeJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemtoupdate), jsonGraphData);          
        //Where the Magic happens (Aka the error)
        RootObject item = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(finalJsonItem);
        return item;
    }
```

Relevant Class

```
  public class RootObject
  {
    public Item item { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, int> daily;
    public Dictionary<string, int> average;
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

}

public class Item
{
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string icon_large { get; set; }
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string typeIcon { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Current current = new Current();
    public Today today { get; set; }
    public string members { get; set; }
    public Prices daily = new Prices();
    public Prices average = new Prices();
    public Day day30 { get; set; }
    public Day day90 { get; set; }
    public Day day180 { get; set; }
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public BsonDocument extraElement { get; set; }
}

public class Prices
{
    public string[] dates;
    public int[] prices;
}

public class Current
{
    public string trend { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class Today
{
    public string trend { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
}

public class Day
{
    public string trend { get; set; }
    public string change { get; set; }
    public int[] averagePrices;
    public int[] currentPrices;
    public string[] dates;
}
```

By adding these two lines of code I have been able to add a temporary fix. I would still love to know why this error occurs and how to fix it.

```
     public static RootObject DeserializeUpdateItem(DataPuller dp,string index, RootObject itemtoupdate)
 {
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    string jsonGraphData = dp.UrlToJson(@"http://services.runescape.com/m=itemdb_rs/api/graph/" + index + ".json");
    if (jsonGraphData == "Null")
    {
        return null;
    }
    string finalJsonItem = JsonMerger.MergeJson(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(itemtoupdate), jsonGraphData);          
    //Where the Magic happens (Aka the error)
    RootObject item = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(finalJsonItem);
    //Temp Fix
    item.item.id = int.Parse(index);
    item.item.extraElement = null;
    return item;
}
```

Comment: What version of MongoDB .Net C# driver are you using ?

Comment: I am using Version 2.2.4 of MongoDB's C# driver.

Comment: The value of integer 2 is not a valid [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/). You could try using `public long _id {get; set;}` instead for integer ids.

Comment: The id field in the Item class is not of ObjectId, it is of int. It should be able to store the integer 2 properly.